# console.error() in Dart?

Tags: dart

How do I do this `console.error(foo);` in Dart?

The `print()` method gets quite close, but it's not exactly what I want. I want to have the notification of an error and the icon along with the stack trace.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's actually very simple to do in Dart:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

main() {
  window.console.error('Something bad occurred');
}
```